# Latest IBM NuGet package for .NET clients obsolete?

Tags: c#, mq

I have a .NET framework 4.7.2 application that connects to an IBM MQ queue. Currently it does this using the older amqmdnet.dll library, which works fine.

I'm trying to modernize this by using the amqmdnetstd.dll which the application can get from NuGet. Using the latest version however (9.3.3), many classes I was using with the old dll are marked as Obsolete, with a note that I should "Use .NET6 based MQ client libraries".

From what I understand from IBM docs and online (and I may very well not understand it correctly at all, as IBM docs are not the best and online info is hard to find), this library for .NET Standard 2.0 should be the way to connect to MQ from my Framework application, and I can't imagine the intent is that IBM wants to force me to .NET Core or whatever other framework.

Even worse, the samples that are included with the IBM MQ installation, from which I was hoping to get a hint of how it is supposed to be done, all use the obsolete classes...

Can anyone with some experience connecting to IBM MQ from a .NET Framework application (preferably using that new NuGet package) tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It tells you to stop using the .netstandard library and switch to .net6+.  Good advice.

Comment: Did you take a look at these `IBMXMSDotnetClient` based example code? - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/master/dotnet

Answer (score -1):

For .NET Framework applications, the way forward is to use MQ .NET Framework libraries(amqmdnet.dll/IBM.XMS.dll) that are shipped with IBM MQ Client packages.

The MQ .NET Standard libraries are deprecated and might be removed by IBM at any point in future. To continue using .NET Framework libraries you could use the MQ .NET Framework libraries shipped with IBM MQ Client package.

If you want to use .NET Framework libraries from Nuget.org you could raise a RFE request with IBM.